# Command line startup switch - new instance of Word and templates opened as documents

Tags: ms-word, command-line-arguments

I am looking for a way to get a shortcut (.lnk file) to open a new instance of Word, and to open any template files (.dot or .dotm) as documents (as if the user had selected 'new' when opening the template).

I have currently specified the following in the target property of the shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" /n "\\myPath\myTemplate.dotm"
```

I have also tried using the following switches:

/n

/t

/f

/z

We are working with Word 2010.

Many thanks for any help!

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a switch that works.... /z

Note in the example below, there is no space between /z and the template name.

This opens a new instance of Word, and a document from the Template.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" /z"\\myPath\myTemplate.dotm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right-click on desktop (or link location)
2. New|Shortcut
3. Specify file in dialog box

[image]

4. Enter path to template (no quotation marks) and click Next
5. Specify Link name and click Finish

If the file associations are correct on your computer, this should launch Word and create a new blank document based on the template.

Comment: Thanks, this was how we tried originally. However, by simply specifying the target template path, we have problems when an existing instance of Word is already running...the document opens in the already running instance of Word. We need it to open a new instance.